# tomcat refresh directory after capistrano deployment

Tags: tomcat, capistrano

I'm successfully configured capistrano to update my Coldfusion project inside tomcat virtual host.

The problem is that Tomcat not see the new "current" directory linked by capistrano, tomcat see the old directory.

Is there a way to say to tomcat to refresh the directory to lookup files? The only solution is to restart tomcat and I want a way to avoid this after each deployment.

Comment: Did you actually redeploy the webapp itself, or just update something within Capistrano?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I update the code with cap deploy command, so capistrano change the current link to a new releases/ directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentaion of Tomcat says:

"If a symbolic link is used for docBase then changes to the symbolic link will only be effective after a Tomcat restart or by undeploying and redeploying the context. A context reload is not sufficient."

So using capistrano in the standard way not work, needing to restart tomcat.

A work around is to put a "production" directory inside the deployment directory and rsync with current after deploy:

```
 task :after_deploy do
     run "rsync -a #{release_path}/* /your/www/directory/production/"
 end
```

With this it's not needed to restart Tomcat.